# How to remove an object from JSON array when checkbox is deselected in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

```
0:
CategoryId: "31b7a227-9fda-4d14-8e1f-1dee5beeccb4"
Code: "GMA0300"
Description: "PA-5215: Renamed"
Enabled: true
Favorite: false
Id: "26cfdb68-ef69-4df0-b4dc-5b9c6501b0dd"
InstrumentType: null
Moniker: "1GMA0300"
Name: "Celiac Disease Panel (tTG IgG, tTG IgA, DGP IgG)"
Tests: Array(3)
  0:
   Code: "GMA0304"
   Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781"
   Name: "Deamidated Gliadin Peptide (DGP) IgG"
 __proto__: Object
  1: {Id: "2fcd610f-d453-4c4f-a8dc-1a5f50e88548", Code: "GMA0301", Name: 
 "Tissue Transglutaminase (tTG) IgA"}
  2: {Id: "de41b236-4866-419a-a6f4-5f7c1440d30f", Code: "GMA0302", Name: 
 "Tissue Transglutaminase (tTG) IgG"}
 length: 3
 __proto__: Array(0)
 TestsSelectable: false
```

hey this is an array selectedPanels object which has another array of objects 
i have mapped this in panel and panel has checkbox and Tests which is an array is expandable rows and has also checkbox

when i check the panel checkbox it checks all the child checkboxes of Tests and shows the length of Tests say 3 
but when i click on each test it should be minus from Tests length say 3 - 1 = 2 it should show 2 now 
but when i use splice it removes the whole row when i deselect the the each test checkbox or the already implementation is when i click on each test it deselect the parent panel checkbox too 
i dont know what to 
what is want is when i deselect the each test 
it should not remove the text but decrease the length of array

you can see from that image

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJUFy.png)

**here is my html file**

```
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [name]="panel.Id + '-' + panel.Moniker" [ngModel]="checkAllTestsSelected(panel)"
      (ngModelChange)="onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event, panel)" [id]="panel.Id + '-' + panel.Moniker">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  </label>

 </ng-template>
 <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
<div class="individual-panel" *ngFor="let test of panel.Tests">
  <span class="text-dimmed">{{test.Name}}</span>
  <span *ngIf="panel.Name.includes('ENA') || panel.Name.includes('Celiac')">
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [name]="test.Id + '-' + test.Code"
           [ngModel]="testSelectionSession.SelectedPanelIds.indexOf(panel.Id) > -1 || testSelectionSession.SelectedPanelIds.indexOf(test.AssociatedPanel?.Id) > -1"
           (ngModelChange)="onTestCheckboxUpdate($event, test, panel)" [id]="test.Id + '-' + test.Code">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

**ts file**

```
checkAllTestsSelected(panel: TestOrderPanel) {
  // get all individual test panels
  let individualTestPanelIds = panel.Tests.reduce((acc, test) => {
   if (test.AssociatedPanel) {
    acc.push(test.AssociatedPanel.Id);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

// check if all individual test panels are selected
let allIndividualTestsSelected = individualTestPanelIds.reduce(
  (acc: boolean, panelId: number) =>
    acc && this.panelIds.indexOf(panelId) > -1,
  individualTestPanelIds.length > 0 &&
  panel.Tests.length === individualTestPanelIds.length
);

// if selected, remove all individual test panels and add the panel group
if (panel.Tests.length > 0 && allIndividualTestsSelected) {
  this.panelIds = this.panelIds.filter(
    panelId => individualTestPanelIds.indexOf(panelId) === -1
  );
  this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.filter(
    selectedPanel => individualTestPanelIds.indexOf(selectedPanel.Id) === -1
  );
  this.panelIds.push(panel.Id);
  this.selectedPanels.push(panel);
  this.updateSession();
 }
  return this.panelIds.indexOf(panel.Id) > -1;
  }


 onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event: boolean, panel: TestOrderPanel) {
   let testPanelIds = panel.Tests.reduce((acc, test) => {
    if (test.AssociatedPanel) {
    acc.push(test.AssociatedPanel.Id);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
// Wipe any duplicates
this.panelIds = this.panelIds.filter(
  panelId => panel.Id !== panelId && testPanelIds.indexOf(panelId) === -1
);
this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.filter(
  selectedPanel =>
    panel.Id !== selectedPanel.Id &&
    testPanelIds.indexOf(selectedPanel.Id) === -1
);

if ($event) {
  this.panelIds.push(panel.Id);
  this.selectedPanels.push(panel);
   }
   this.updateSession();
 }

 onTestCheckboxUpdate($event: boolean,
                   test: TestOrderPanelTest,
                   panel: TestOrderPanel) {


let testPanelIds = panel.Tests.reduce((acc, test) => {
  if (test.AssociatedPanel) {
    acc.push(test.AssociatedPanel.Id);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
let associatedTestPanels = this.testSelectionSession.IndividualTestPanelsForAll.filter(
  testPanel => testPanelIds.indexOf(testPanel.Id) > -1
);

let clickedTestPanel = associatedTestPanels.find(
  testPanel => (test.AssociatedPanel ? test.AssociatedPanel.Id : -1) === testPanel.Id
);


if (clickedTestPanel) {
  // Wipe any duplicates
  this.panelIds = this.panelIds.filter(
    panelId => clickedTestPanel.Id !== panelId
  );
  this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.filter(
    panel => clickedTestPanel.Id !== panel.Id
  );

  // Add individual panel if checkbox selected
  if ($event) {
    this.panelIds = this.panelIds.concat(clickedTestPanel.Id);
    console.log(this.panelIds)
    this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.concat(clickedTestPanel);
    console.log(this.selectedPanels)
  }
  }
  this.updateSession();
 }
```

array is in this.selectedPanels 
how to solve this issue 
can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you add an index to the ngfor loop in your template ('let i = index' in the code below), you can pass this to your onTestCheckboxUpdate() function and splice the source array at this point:

HTML file:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="I">
        {{item}}
        <button (click)="removeItem(i)">Remove '{{item}}' from array</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

TS file:

```
items = ['cat','dog','mouse','frog','horse','bird'];

removeItem(itemIndex:number){
    this.items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
}
```

Does this achieve what you're looking for? Example of the basic concept [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asmats).

Comment: this.panel.Tests.splice(arrayIndex,i) where is this i coming from?

Comment: Sorry I've updated the example code so it's clearer what's happening. The i from the  template (which is the index of each item) is passed to the removeItem function, which removes one item from the array at that index. Is the behaviour of the Stackblitz what you're expecting?

Comment: i have added my image you can get an idea from that

Comment: Ah sorry that was a mistake - should have been a 1, as in, remove one item starting at index  arrayIndex.

Comment: i have applied that but it removing the whole like when i uncheck the test it gets deleted

Comment: Are you looking for a counter, so if two checkboxes are selected, the number of available tests is reduced by two, but they're not removed from the array?

Comment: no no i what i simply want is when i uncheck the individual test the counter should reduced by one but what it is doing right now is reducing the counter but removing the whole row as well idk why is that

Comment: Are you using Angular material checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach to get the number of items which are checked, or not checked. **Updated** to add 'checked' property to each item in data array, below and on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asmats).

TS File:

```
items = [
    {name: 'cat'},
    {name: 'dog'},
    {name: 'horse'},
    {name: 'mouse'}
];

checkCount = this.items.length;

checkItem(itemIndex:number){
    if(this.items[itemIndex]['checked'] === undefined){
        this.items[itemIndex]['checked'] = false;
    } else {
        this.items[itemIndex]['checked'] = !this.items[itemIndex]['checked'];
    }
    this.checkCount = this.items.filter(item => item['checked'] === true || item['checked'] === undefined).length;
}
```

HTML File:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <label>{{item.name}}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked (click)="checkItem(i)">
    </li>
</ul>

Check count: {{checkCount}}
```

Example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asmats).

If you needed two-way binding, you could use a [formControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) to hold the 'checked' variable for each checkbox, rather than a plain boolean. You can see an example of this [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yp6fg4).

Comment: but there is not checked flag coming from backend

Comment: This approach will still work with a slight adjustment - you just need to check for ‘item[itemIndex][‘checked’] === undefined’ at the beginning of the checkItem function. If it is undefined, you add it as a property to the item object and, set it to false. if it isn’t undefined, you reverse the value as per the example. Then in the array filter function, you check for ‘checked === undefined || checked === true’. I’m away from my machine right now, but will update my answer later.

Comment: yeah sure please update it so i can have a better understanding thanks btw :)

Comment: Have updated my answer - let me know how you get on!

Comment: i was busy these 2 days i will implement it and let you know 
thanks tho :)

Comment: I'd like to help but you've posted a lot of code so it's difficult to debug. If you make a Stackblitz with a sample of the panel.Tests JSON  and as simple logic as possible, I'll have a look.